# execute sql query in php using concatenation

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql can't perform more than 1 query at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942766/mysql-cant-perform-more-than-1-query-at-a-time)

```
        $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE nw_world;";
        $query = $query . " INSERT INTO `nw_world`";
        $query = $query . " SELECT * FROM `x_world` WHERE x <0 AND y >=0";
        $query = $query . " AND tid !=5 AND aid NOT IN ( 29, 908, 935, 941, 950 )";
        $query = $query . " AND population <=50";

        echo "$query";
        mysql_query($query,$con) or die("error ".mysql_error());
```

This results in an error

```
error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `nw_world` SELECT * FROM `x_world` WHERE x <0 AND y >=0 AND tid !=5 ' at line 1
```

But when i execute the same query in mysql it works fine. Due to which i am having a feeling that i am making some mistake in the php coding. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP, by default, will only execute 1 query per mysql_query call (security measure).

If you want to execute more than one at a time look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query` does not let you execute more than 1 query. Use [mysqli::multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) 
or execute each command separately.